# Angular get only required data from array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ng-repeat and it gets all the data, but I require only certain data from the provided source

HTML

```
<tr ng-repeat="val in values ">
    <td ng-bind="$index"></td>
    <td ng-bind="val.rec">ED1500322</td> 
    <td>working</td>
    <td ng-bind="val.result">I am going to School</td>
    <td>
      <div class="radio">
        <input ng-model="val.iscorrect" value="yes" type="radio">
        <label for="opt1">yes</label>
        <input ng-model="val.iscorrect" value="no" type="radio">
        <label for="opt10">no</label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

data

```
$scope.values = [{
    name: "John",
    rec:234,
    iscorrect: ''
  }, {
    name: "Paul",
    rec:44,
    iscorrect: ''
  }, {
    name: "George",
    rec:2664,
    iscorrect: 'no'
  }, {
    name: "Ringo",
    rec:124,
    iscorrect: 'yes'
  }];
```

we can see I have certain values where iscorrect=" ". I only wanted that corresponding values to be in my $scope.values and html

plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/f0l7MHN7UAvOLNZ8BCjV?p=preview

Any help in getting data where iscorrect=" " is appreciated...

Comment: i don't understand what you want .. you want to hide the inputs where iscorrect is ' ' ??

Comment: yes it's not very clear what you are asking

Comment: I actually want to display all checkbox with their corresponding values, which does not have either yes/no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like below in your `ng-repeat` to filter the values

```
<tr ng-repeat="val in getValues(values) ">
  <td ng-bind="$index"></td>
  <td ng-bind="val.rec">ED1500322</td> 
  <td>working</td>
  <td ng-bind="val.result">I am going to School</td>
  <td>
   <div class="radio">
    <input ng-model="val.iscorrect" value="yes" type="radio">
    <label for="opt1">yes</label>
    <input ng-model="val.iscorrect" value="no" type="radio">
    <label for="opt10">no</label>
   </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Then in controller:

```
$scope.getValues = function (values) {
  return values.filter(function (item) {
    return item.iscorrect === '';
  });
}
```

I would suggest not to use a filter because they add a lot of watchers and trigger digest cycle, which is bad for UI performance

UPDATE: Add plunkr link: http://plnkr.co/edit/3GJZca8YLnW4P0BGulfq?p=preview

Comment: could you please update plunker...this would be helpful..thanks

Answer (score 3):

So you only want to show those where iscorrect=''?

Try this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="val in values" ng-if="!val.iscorrect">
```

Amended the answer to rid it of the filter, and use ng-if instead which is cleaner [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/GRBp1WvjbaoBFnx6qWw7?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div ng-repeat="val in values | filter : val.iscorrect='no'">
    <input ng-model="val.iscorrect" value="yes" type="radio">
    <label for="opt1">yes</label>
    <input ng-model="val.iscorrect" value="no" type="radio">
    <label for="opt10">no</label>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.values = [{
    name: "John",
    rec: 234,
    iscorrect: 'no'
  }, {
    name: "Paul",
    rec: 44,
    iscorrect: 'yes'
  }, {
    name: "George",
    rec: 2664,
    iscorrect: 'no'
  }, {
    name: "Ringo",
    rec: 124,
    iscorrect: 'yes'
  }];
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```